# QDialogButtonBox buttons not responding

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-designer, qdialog

When I run the following function, the dialog shows with everything in place. The problem is that the buttons won't connect. OK and Cancel do not response to mouse clicks.

```
void MainWindow::initializeBOX(){

        QDialog dlg;
        QVBoxLayout la(&dlg);
        QLineEdit ed;
        la.addWidget(&ed);


        //QDialogButtonBox bb(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
        //btnbox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
         QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok |     QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

         connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
         connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

         la.addWidget(buttonBox);
         dlg.setLayout(&la);


        if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        {
            mTabWidget->setTabText(0, ed.text());
        }

      }
```

At runtime, an error in the cmd shows: No such slots as accept() and reject().

Comment: Do you have `accept()` and `reject()` slots in your `MainWindow` ?

Comment: no that is what i am trying to do. i added Void accept(), but it doesnt work. i am new to Qt, can you please show me how to add the SLOT thank you @Nejat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are specifying the wrong receiver in the connection. It's the dialog that has the `accept()` and `reject()` slots, not the main window (i.e. `this`).

So, instead, you just need:

```
 connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), &dlg, SLOT(accept()));
 connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), &dlg, SLOT(reject()));
```

And now when you click the buttons, the dialog will close, and `exec()` will return either `QDialog::Accepted` for OK, or `QDialog::Rejected` for Cancel.